# How do you get the ip address of a remote EJB client in Glassfish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

Like the title says:

I have a Swing standalone client which connects to an EJB application deployed on GF 3.0.1. I'd like to have access to client IP inside EJB methods.

Is this possible?

I also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014358/how-can-you-get-the-calling-ip-address-on-an-ejb-call) but the solution was for JBoss...

Comment: Maybe you've already thought of this, but as a work around you could provide a web service that accesses the EJB(s). It may be more work but at least it should get you where you need.

Comment: I'll probably implement smth like this if I don't find a more direct approach. Thanks.

Comment: Kind of pathetic that there's no native methods to do this in the Java API.

Answer (score 1):

```
@WebService()
public class Test {

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext context;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "getInfo")
    public String getInfo() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getMessageContext()
                .get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
        return "IP: " + request.getRemoteAddr() +
                ", Port: " + request.getRemotePort() +
                ", Host: " + request.getRemoteHost();
    }
}
```