# How to get the address of the calling remote client of an EJB method in JBoss AS7

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

i have a distributed application that consists of one server, the JBoss AS7 on which the frontend and the backend of the application run.
Several clients, running on other machines in a network obtain the JNDI initial context of the JBoss to get certain objects.
Each client is unique and needs to be identified without doing any configuration on them. My approach is to get their address and map the data related to them (pool of stuff, evenly mapped between all connected clients).

**How can i obtain the IP address of the calling client of an EJB method?**

I already found 'hacks' that describe how to get the information out of the thread name (used for example in JBoss 4.x), but that always returns something like:

> EJB default - 7

See [How can you get the calling ip address on an ejb call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014358/how-can-you-get-the-calling-ip-address-on-an-ejb-call)

If you provide a code snippet or a method call on some context, can you please add the source of it? I was unable to find something by searching for *EJB3*, *Remoting3* and similar stuff

Comment: What about the alternative of using ejb security and identify each client through his authentification, i.e. the callerPrincipal() on the EJB context? Just an idea.

Comment: I tried using your solution but end up getting the anonymous principal since i dont lookup _ejb:/_ context, but _java:/_ context. Authentication is done through the AdministrationRealm of JBoss, no extra security is added. I know that it is possible to do what I want using RMI, but i would prefer to use EJBs.

Comment: Have a look at this description, I haven't tried it myself but it looks like this is a way to identify the caller in the bean: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss7AndEjbRemoteCallWithSecurity

Comment: Implemented that method, still **anonymous**. I guess i will do something else: Register each client through a EJB remote method, returning a unique id generated by the server. The client then does some heartbeat mechanism (poll the server once every x seconds) with its id. I guess that could be a workaround to see how many clients are active and can do some work. However i wont be able to say "The client with id 1234 is located there".

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea,

May be use can expose your ejb through a rest based web service layer. If you do so it is easy to find remote host name and may also use filter servlet to allow or disallow a request.

You can use @EJB to inject your bean into rest class assuming you will use JAX-RS.