# Obtaining remote client IP in an AuthorizationModule on JBoss 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jaas

Our application relies on an `AuthorizationModule` for filtering certain IP addresses in a remoting context. This module worked perfectly on **JBoss 5.1.0.GA** ([with a known workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014358/how-can-you-get-the-calling-ip-address-on-an-ejb-call)), but failes on **EAP-6.1.0.Alpha**, since the `Thread` name pattern has changed significantly.

**Q: Is it possible to obtain the client IP address in the following context?**

```
import org.jboss.security.authorization.modules.AbstractAuthorizationModule;

public class MyAuthorizationModule extends AbstractAuthorizationModule {
  @Override
  public int authorize(Resource resource) {
        //Caller is a standalone Java client, that connects to JBoss 7.x using EJB Remoting
        String callerIP = ...; 
  }
}
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Calling `java.rmi.server.RemoteServer.getClientHost()`. This results in `ServerNotActiveException`.
2. Parsing `JBossThread` name ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014358/how-can-you-get-the-calling-ip-address-on-an-ejb-call) [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954870/how-to-get-the-address-of-the-calling-remote-client-of-an-ejb-method-in-jboss-as?lq=1)).

Comment: Why not filtering IP addresses by JBoss configuration, with the org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve valve ?

Comment: @Thomas: I think this would only be useful in a [web](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/using-web-valves-with-jboss-7) module, and not for filtering _remoting_ connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with some help from the [JBoss Community](https://community.jboss.org/thread/224267). However, this isn't an elegant solution, since I ended up patching the internals of the application server (EJB3 module). Check out the community post for more details.